# How to text wrap selected values in a pickerInput (from shinyWidgets package). Make the height of the selector change as to accommodate multiple lines

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

The selected values always appear in the pickerInput in one line. When multiple choices are selected - many of them don't fit into 1 line and are not visible (unless one opens the drop-down menu and scrolls down to see if they are selected or not).
How can the pickerInput widget resize (height wise) to show all the choices (adding new lines if needed) - much like the selectInput can do? I'd like to use pickerInput (instead of the standard selectInput)because of its features like "Select All", "Deselect All".

I've tried setting pickerOptions attribute:

```
multipleSeparator="<br>"
```

then, the selected values do appear on several lines, but the selector's container doesn't wrap around them, i.e.:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhEv9.png

While ideally I'd like to see something like this:
[This is how it works well with standard selectInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bZKI.png)